# iis reverse proxy rule fail with the same virtual directory

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I have two urls,

the first one looks like: localhost1/api/test/2.0/aaa

the second one looks like: localhost2/api/test/3.0/aaa

when using localhost1/api/test/3.0/aaa ,I want rewrite to localhost2/api/test/3.0/aaa. 
My rewrite map : original value is localhost1 and new value is localhost2

My inbound rule is api/(.+)/3.0/(.+), url match is https://{C:0}/api/{R:1}/3.0/{R:2}

When I use localhost1/api/test/3.0/aaa
I always get response from localhost1/api/test/2.0/aaa , but I really want is 
localhost2/api/test/3.0/aaa
Please tell me how to fix it.

(ps: if using localhost1/api/test2/3.0/aaa , I can get the correct response from localhost2/api/test2/3.0/aaa.  ,but exists  locahost1/api/test)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the C:0 will match the condition pattern not the inbound pattern. Besides, I found you just write the rule to match the  `localhost1/api/test/3.0/aaa` not the `api/test/2.0/aaa`.

If you want to let the 2.0 also rewrite to the localhost2, I suggest you could add below url rewrite rule.

```
            <rule name="Teeee">
                <match url="api/(.+)/2.0/(.+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost2/api/{R:1}/2.0/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: I just want using the 3.0 to rewrite to another url.